# The legend of the geom that I am trying to build does not vary in size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing my own GEOM by extending ggplot2.

```
GeomTimeLine <- ggproto("GeomTimeLine", Geom,
                         required_aes = c("x"),
                        default_aes = aes(size = .02, shape = 19, alpha=.3, y=.5,
                                          colour="black", fill="black",fontsize=1),
                         draw_key = draw_key_dotplot,
                         draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord) {}
)
```

In the actual legend, all of the dots appear to be the same size even if the data does vary in size.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you want `draw_key_point` instead of `draw_key_dotplot`?  As far as I know, dotplots in ggplot2 don't use the `size` aesthetic.

Comment: If I use draw_key_point I get this error: "Error in check.length(gparname) : 
  'gpar' element 'fontsize' must not be length 0"